# SPO restrict few selected file extension

Tags: sharepoint-online, onedrive

Came across the article that  there is no restriction in any file extension in the SPO https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/types-of-files-that-cannot-be-added-to-a-list-or-library-30be234d-e551-4c2a-8de8-f8546ffbf5b3

**No restrictions to types of files added to SharePoint**

but we can restrict it using Sync Client
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/block-file-types

Is there any alternative way to control upload to the OneDrive Site when user clicks on the upload option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no OOB ways to restrict specific file extensions in SharePoint Online. You can create a workflow that start automatically when an item is created. and use "delete List Item" action when the file type is equal to relevant type.

Here is a similar post for your reference:

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/244847/how-to-restrict-files-uploaded-to-sharepoint-online